# Show that $1+z=2\cos\frac 12\theta(\cos\frac 12 \theta + i\sin \frac 12 \theta)$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

> Let $z=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$. Show that $1+z=2\cos\frac 12\theta(\cos\frac 12 \theta + i\sin \frac 12 \theta)$

Can anyone show me how to show the equation? I can't think of how to get $\frac 12 \theta$ from $\cos\theta$ and $\sin\theta$.

Comment: Here your $z$ is on the unit circle.  If you like you can even prove this using geometry.

Comment: @Nilan I would like to know how I can prove this using geometry? After seeing your comment, I've been trying to do so. however, I have gotten nowhere. Please give a hint?

Comment: @Gummybears: $z$, $1+z$, $1$, and $0$ are vertices of a rhombus.

Comment: @Blue Oh that is true.

Answer (score 6):

Half angle formula: We will manipulate the RHS-1.

RHS= $2\cos^2(\theta/2)-1+i2\cos(\theta/2)\sin(\theta/2)=\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)=z$

Comment: Was just about to post it as a comment. +1

Comment: @Gummybears: Thanks. I usuallt want to view the formatting while typing, and comments do not allow that :).

Answer (score 0):

$$
\cos\frac{1}{2}\theta + i\sin\frac{1}{2}\theta = \mathrm{e}^{i\frac{1}{2}\theta}
$$
using
$$
\frac{\mathrm{e}^{i\frac{1}{2}\theta} + \mathrm{e}^{-i\frac{1}{2}\theta}}{2} = \cos \frac{1}{2}\theta
$$
we get
$$
\left(\mathrm{e}^{i\frac{1}{2}\theta} + \mathrm{e}^{-i\frac{1}{2}\theta}\right)\mathrm{e}^{i\frac{1}{2}\theta} = \mathrm{e}^{i\theta} + 1 = z+1
$$

Answer (score 0):

Two relations may help

\begin{eqnarray}
\sin \theta \cos \phi     &=& \frac{\sin(\theta + \phi)+\sin(\theta-\phi)}{2} \\
\cos^{2} \frac{\theta}{2} &=& \frac{1+\cos \theta}{2}
\end{eqnarray}